# How to detect which window is focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, focus

How can you in Javascript detect an active window?

Ok, I want to open up 3 windows. These 3 windows are menus and will be used to modify number of other windows.

Think of it like a paint program. You have 2 windows for tools and 1 for content. However, think about that 1 window for content but instead it's not restricted to just one. You can have 12 windows for content to change or add stuff too...etc.

So, with JavaScript I want to know what window is focused?  3 windows will be like tools. Then there could be 1 to 12 or more windows opened that has content for edit. However, I need to know how can JavaScript focus on 1 window that the user has select or is currently monkeying around with?

I just want the user to be able to edit or work with one content page at a time while having all them open up as individual windows.

So for example:  I have 3 windows that are tool menu windows. Lets say I open 12 individual windows that have images in them. I plan to modify and edit them.

How can I get javascript to focus on one window at a time. So, if I lets say change the background color of the image to red. I don't want to change all 12 windows contents to a background with red. Instead lets say I want to change the background color of window 10 out of the 1 to 12 content windows.

How can I zero in on that one window to work with. However, I must be able to zero in on it based on what the user does. Like for example clicks that window which gets selected or focused on. So, the user just has to click on that window that they want to work on.

So, if I clicked on that content window 10. I will modify only that window. Then quickly I can click content window 5 and the focus will change to that window content 5.  So, if I change that background to blue it will only change content window 5's background color to blue and not content window 10.

From what I see I would need to check if the window is focus property is true or if blur is true. However, I need to trigger an event when the focus properties of any of the windows change.

How would one do this?

Comment: Are these windows actual browser windows or just ui components?

Comment: I am talking about actual windows. In javascript it be  code :  window.open('url here');      you can call it a popup window but not talking about the alert window. These are actual individual browser windows that are opened from one single browser window aka the main browser window.

Comment: I have seen many tutorials and sources online that only checks for the blur and focus properties. However, they would add the feature to make it false or true to enable or disable the focus. I just need  a way to to know what content window was selected so the person can add stuff to that window or delete stuff from it. I just need to separate it. I know how to manually refer to the windows manually. However, I want the user to select just one window to work with at a time.  I am thinking to have a variable on the main browser window that opened up those window with a variable and update that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API). Perhaps in combination with [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) to keep the state of your application consistent. For example, you could set an "activeWindow" key in the localStorage database when a page gets focus, then have your other windows respond to a StorageEvent when that key changes.

Comment: [localStorage](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage),

[pageVisibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pagevisibility)